# WordPress event schedule not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, events, cron, schedule

I have used some code to run the event schedule run a WP Cron job every 3 minutes. But this code runs continuously, not worked time interval.  I have used wp_mail for testing and received almost 200 hundred in 10min. How can I overcome this problem? 
[image]
**Code**

```
function isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 180,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 3 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval' );

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'your_three_minute_action_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'your_three_minute_action_hook' );
}
add_action('your_three_minute_action_hook', 'isa_test_cron_job_send_mail');

function isa_test_cron_job_send_mail() {
    $to         = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';
    $subject    = 'Test my 3-minute cron job';
    $message    = 'If you received this message, it means that your 3-minute cron job has worked! :) ';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by disable WP-Cron?
WP-Cron can be disabled in the wp-config.php file. Open the wp-config.php file for editing and add the following line:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Can you try your code after this?